# Use OpenCV to detect text blocks to send to Tesseract iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, ocr, tesseract

How can I use OpenCV to detect all the text in an image, I want to to be able to detect "blocks" of texts individually. Then pass the the recognized blocks into tesseract. Here is an example, if I were to scan this I would want to scan the paragraphs separately, not go from left to right which is what tesseract does.

[Image of the example](http://cdn.designrshub.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/alignment.jpg)

Comment: The accepted answer by user2518618 is great. I want to comment that tesseract can also give you the data, not only the text. Therefore you can loop over the data and consider each block (block_number) individually (reconstruct the text yourself by adding newline between lines and spaces between text pieces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be my first test:

- Threshold the image to get a black and white image, with the text in black
- Erode it until the paragraph converts to a big blob. It may have lots of holes, it doesn't matter.
- Find contours and the bounding box

If some paragraphs merge, you should erode less or dilate a little bit after the erode.